# Regular expression to match version numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that is matching below criteria

For example : below should be matched

```
1
1134
1.1
1.4.5.6
```

Those below should not match:

```
.1
1.
1..6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ1tK0/3)

- `^` - beginning of string
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(\.\d+)*` - a group matching 0 or more sequences of `.` + 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

You can use a non-capturing group, too: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$`, but it is not so necessary here.

Comment: Hi..above regular expression works in IE but nothing happens in Firefox.

Comment: I doubt it is a problem with the regex. You can try with `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$`, and if it is not working, the problem is somewhere else.